# Android приложение перестало работать

Tags: java, android, android-threads

Написал приложение, которое принимает *JSON* с сервера и результат выводит в `RecyclerView`. Изначально все работало корректно, но через некоторое время стало зависать на `ProgressBar` в *Android 5.0*. На эмуляторе *Android studio* все работает отлично (эмулятор *Android 7.1.1*). Зависает в фоновом потоке при десериализации *JSON*.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context;
ProgressBar progressBar;
RecyclerView filmView;
Activity main;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    main = this;
    context=this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    filmView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.FilmsList);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

        MyThread myThread = new MyThread();
        Thread thread = new Thread(myThread);
        thread.start();
}

/**
 * Класс для обработки Json
 */
public class MyThread extends Thread{
    private final long date=System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L;
    private final String FILMS_URL ="http://example.com"
    private String resultJson;
    private JSONObject jsonObject;
    private JSONArray js;
    Adapter adapter;
    private Films[] films;
    InputStream inputStream;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(FILMS_URL);
            URLConnection http = url.openConnection();
            inputStream = http.getInputStream();
            http.connect();
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            resultJson = buffer.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultJson);
            js = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
            films =new Gson().fromJson(js.toString(), Films[].class); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        filmView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                filmView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(50));
                filmView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                adapter = new Adapter(main, context, films);
                LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(main);
                llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                filmView.setLayoutManager(llm);
                filmView.setAdapter(adapter);

                /**
                 * Обработка нажатий
                 */
                filmView.addOnItemTouchListener(
                        new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FilmDetails.class);
                                String filmString;
                                GsonBuilder gsonBuilder=new GsonBuilder();
                                gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Films.class, new MyTypeAdapter());
                                gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting();
                                Gson gson=gsonBuilder.create();
                                filmString =gson.toJson(films[position]);
                                intent.putExtra("films", filmString);       //передаём объект как json-строку
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        })
                );
            }
        });
    }
}


public void onProgressClick(View view){
    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

в логи пишет это

```
01-13 13:45:31.464 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending          all threads took: 53.907ms
01-13 13:45:33.422 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.432ms
01-13 13:45:35.849 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 9256(454KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(47KB)      LOS objects, 21% free, 2017KB/2MB, paused 4.327ms total 312.016ms
01-13 13:45:35.876 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 24.495ms
01-13 13:45:35.953 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 34.178ms
01-13 13:45:36.939 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.087ms
01-13 13:45:38.017 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 90.718ms
01-13 13:45:39.033 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 106.362ms
01-13 13:45:39.123 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5725(315KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB)   LOS objects, 13% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 3.789ms total 499.241ms
01-13 13:45:39.565 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending   all threads took: 140.064ms
01-13 13:45:39.734 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8075(378KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS      objects, 39% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 2.541ms total 374.222ms
01-13 13:45:39.756 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.256ms
01-13 13:45:41.457 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 10.842ms
01-13 13:45:42.026 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.661ms
01-13 13:45:42.306 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 26452(1138KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)   LOS objects, 38% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 3.173ms total 350.458ms
01-13 13:45:42.340 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 32.739ms
01-13 13:45:42.478 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 45.701ms
01-13 13:45:42.941 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.528ms
01-13 13:45:43.441 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.983ms
01-13 13:45:43.967 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.002ms
01-13 13:45:44.441 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.679ms
01-13 13:45:45.017 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 78.054ms
01-13 13:45:45.227 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 30991(1278KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 4.014ms total 530.324ms
01-13 13:45:45.248 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 20.060ms
01-13 13:45:46.952 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.040ms
01-13 13:45:47.519 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 24262(1051KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 28.907ms total 413.226ms
01-13 13:45:47.522 1353-1364/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 276.630ms for cause HeapTrim
01-13 13:45:47.621 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 93.925ms
01-13 13:45:47.952 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.986ms
01-13 13:45:48.445 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.285ms
01-13 13:45:49.451 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.622ms
01-13 13:45:49.977 1353-1360/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.428ms
01-13 13:45:50.156 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.254ms
01-13 13:45:50.407 1353-1365/com.example.sharafievp.myfilm I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 27212(1124KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 31% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 11.058ms total 474.047ms
```

на *english* форумах пишут что проблема связана не с кодом, а с *Android 5.0*.
Пользуюсь библиотекой *Gson*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем ни одна из библиотек обработки *JSON* у меня не работает на *Android 5.0*. Написал собственный класс для обработки, используя стандартную библиотеку *org.json*. Теперь приложение не зависает.

Comment: Стоило бы уточнить, какая именно библиотека.

Answer (score 1):

```
filmView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Нужен только в том случае, если у вас все ячейки одинаковой высоты.
Если у вас высота зависит от контента, просто удалите эту строчку, в противном случае, это может вызывать лаги

Comment: ячейки все одинаковые, раньше приложение с этой строчкой работало